# Capitalize first letter of sentence in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I wish to capitalize the first letter of a sentence, on-the-fly, as the user types the text in a CKEditor content instance.

The strategy consists in catching each keystroke and try to replace it when necessary, that is for instance, when the inserted character follows a dot and a space. I'm fine with catching the event, but can't find a way to parse characters surrounding the caret position:

```js
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances.htmlarea
instance.document.getBody().on('keyup', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // Would like to parse here from the event object...
    event.data.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated including a strategy alternative.

Comment: could  you please post your full code ? I'm searchig exactly what you did !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `keydown` event (close to what you proposed):

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

editor.document.getBody().on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.data.getKeystroke() === 65 /*a*/ && isFirstLetter()) {
        // insert 'A' instead of 'a'
        editor.insertText('A');
        event.data.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Now - how should `isFirstLetter()` look like?

1. You have to start from `editor.getSelection().getRanges()` to get caret position.
2. You're interested only in the first range from the collection.
3. To extract text content from before the caret use small trick:

   - move start of the range to the beginning of document: `range.setStartAt( editor.document.getBody(), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START )`,
   - use `CKEDITOR.dom.walker` to traverse through DOM tree in source order,
   - collect text nodes and find out what's before caret (is it `/\. $/`) - remember that you have to skip inline tags and stop on block tags - hint: return `false` from `guard` function to stop traversing.

Example of how you can use `walker` on `range`:

```js
var range, walker, node;

range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
range.setStartAt(editor.document.getBody(), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START);
walker = new CKEDITOR.dom.walker(range);
walker.guard = function(node) {
    console.log(node);
};

while (node = walker.previous()) {}
```

And now few sad things.

- We assumed that selection is empty when you type - that doesn't have to be true. When selection is not collapsed (empty) then you'll have to manually remove its content before calling `insertText`. You can use `range#deleteContents` to do this.
- But this is not all - after deleting range's content you have to place caret in correct position - this isn't trivial. Basically you can use `range#select` (on the range after `deleteContents`), but in some cases it can place caret in incorrect place - like between paragraphs. Fixing this is... is not doable without deeeeeeeep knowledge about HTML+editables+insertions+other things :).
- This solution is not complete - you have to handle `paste` event, deleting content (one can delete words from the start of sentence), etc, etc.
- I guess there are couple of other problems I didn't even thought about :P.

So this approach isn't realistic. If you still want to implement this feature I think that you should set timer and by traversing DOM (you can use `walker` on range containing entire document, or recently typed text (hard to find out where it is)) find all sentences starting from lower letter and fix them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Reinmar. Regarding the sad things, I won't implement those particular event contexts. In deed, they're ways to work around this capitalizing feature, and that's pretty helpful to handle exceptions.

Comment: I am also searching for the same thing but where can I write the above code.I tried in JavaScript but it didn't raise the key event it is not working where I can write this can any one help me out.thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Ckeditor 4.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

editor.document.getBody().on('keydown', function(event) {

    if (event.data.getKeystroke() >= 65 && event.data.getKeystroke()<=91 && encodeURI(this.getText())=="%0A" && this.getText().length==1 ) {
        //uppercase the char
        editor.insertText(String.fromCharCode(event.data.getKeystroke()));
        event.data.preventDefault();
    }
});
```