# How can i convert first letter of a string or after a "." to upper case in CKEditor (for maximum performance)

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I have CKEditor and also I need to entering data. That is the first letter is display in Capital letter string Upper case and after `.` (full stop) also I need to display again capital letter string Upper letter in the CKEditor

I want to display like this
 For example:

```
this is a string. i need to implement.. ---> This is a string. I need to implement..
```

I want to display "this is a string" in that first letter of sentence "this" will make to capital "T" "This" and after `.` (full-stop) "i" will also make capital "I".  How can i display can any one help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize first letter of sentence in CKeditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226226/capitalize-first-letter-of-sentence-in-ckeditor)

Comment: I am unable to understand where to implement this can you provide me

Comment: can you please provide me for code your post the link i used that code it's not working

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
 CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
  e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
  e.editor.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
 CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditor1.on('contentDom', function () {
 CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditor1.document.on('keyup', function (event) {/*your instructions*/ });
   });   }  );  });   }); </script>'  I have a code but it didn't work what i miss i don't know it didn't raise the key up event can anyone tell me to how to do this.